# Complex number in quadratic equation

Tags: complex-numbers, quadratics

Find $a,b$ given that a root of $x= 1+2i$ and the equation $ x^2+(a+bi)x+2i-1=0$
I tried finding it by $\Delta$,
which I got $\Delta=a^2+2abi-b^2-8i+4$
I tried substituting the root into the equation but still can't continue.
Can you help me?

Comment: @GNU Thanks for the edit, never heard of the "delta method"; is this another way of saying the quadratic method?

Comment: @BLAZE I think about this for a while, and I don't think that it's really another way of solving the problem, it's just another "label".

Answer (score 1):

Let $x_2$ be the other root of $x^2+(a+bi)x+2i-1$. Then $x_1x_2=2i-1$. Hence $x_2=(2i-1)/(1+2i)=\frac{3}{5}+\frac{4 i}{5}$. Thus $a+bi=-(x_1+x_2)=-(\frac{8}{5}+\frac{14 i}{5})$.

Answer (score 0):

If you specifically want to do this via the quadratic method (which is not the easiest method as you could use the sum and product of roots to get two expressions that can be solved simultaneously).

But continuing with your method anyway:

Using the quadratic formula for a general quadratic $ax^2+bx+c$ which is
$$x=\frac{-b\pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$$

$$x=\frac{-a-bi\pm \sqrt{(a+bi)^2-4\cdot 1 \cdot (2i-1)}}{2\cdot 1}$$
Since $x=1+2i$ is a solution

$$\frac{-a-bi\pm \sqrt{(a^2+2abi -b^2-8i+4)}}{2}=1+2i$$

$$\implies{\pm \sqrt{a^2+2abi -b^2-8i+4}}=2+a+(4+b)i$$

$$\implies{{a^2+2abi -b^2-8i+4}}=\left(2+a+(4+b)i\right)^2\tag{1}$$

Now simplify ($1$) and equate for the real and imaginary components to find the value of $a$ and $b$.

Comment: why is this equal to zero?

Comment: it is given a root $x_1=1+2i$ of the quadratic $f=x^2+(a+bi)x+2i-1$. How does from this follow that every root of $f$ is 0?

Comment: @math635 It doesn't; you were right, thanks